# How to select unknown element in react native webview?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aframe

I'm doing my personal project using React Native and Aframe.

I want to change a-frame panorama image element using javascript.

#### Scenario

1. init aframe rendering.
2. select image from iOS photo library (camera roll) using `<input type='file' />`
3. select `<a-sky>` element by javascript selector
4. change `<a-sky>` element's src attribute to new photo by photo library

In Chrome browser, above scenario is work. 
But In react native webview, not working. I tracked bug, I discovered problem that Webview can't found `<a-sky>` element. I found message about `HTMLUnknownElement`.

How to select unknown element in react native webview?
I tried to select using jquery selector(`$`), getElementById. but doesn't work.

#### static html

```
<a-scene>
    <a-sky id="panoImage" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

#### static html's script

```
inputFile.addEventListener("change", function() {
    const input = this;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('a-sky')[0].setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        };
    }
});
```

#### React-Native index.ios.js

```
<View>
    <WebView ref={webView => { this.webView = webView; }}
            source={require('./src/static.html')}
    />
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it HTML5? If not try adding that.

Comment: this is html5. top of index, I added `<!DOCTYPE html>`